# C# How to use event in the inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance, events

I'm trying to implement an `event` for logging:

In the following example, all works well:

```
public class BaseElement
{
    internal delegate void ReportWriter(string report);
    internal event ReportWriter Log;

    internal void Click()
    {
            WebElement.Click();
            Log?.Invoke("The " + Name + " is clicked");
    }
}
```

But when I try to use `Log` in the inherited class, the methods on the `Log` aren't allowed to be used.

```
public class Button : BaseElement
{
    //....

    internal void Clear()
    {
            WebElement.Clear();
            Log.//not allowed any methods
    }
}
```

I do not want to initialize the delegate and `Log` an event each time in each class - how do I use one `event` for all cases?
[image]

Comment: `Log += ...` press tab twice

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-raise-base-class-events-in-derived-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following method to your BaseElement class:

```
internal void LogInvoke(string report)
{
    Log?.Invoke(report);
}
```

Then you can invoke it from the inherited Button class by calling the LogInvoke method.

```
public class Button : BaseElement
{
    //....

    internal void Clear()
    {
            WebElement.Clear();
            LogInvoke("clear");
    }
}
```